# How many Blast Shapes / Eldritch Essences can a Warlock combine?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, warlock, eldritch-invocations

A Warlock can apply Blast Shapes and Eldritch Essences to his/her Eldritch Blast ability. These alter the effect and/or shape of the Eldritch Blast.
My question is: How many Blast Shapes and how many Eldritch Essences can be applied to a single instance of Eldritch Blast?

And how does this interact with feats that change the shape of the Eldritch Blast, without officially being "Blast Shapes", specifically the Eldritch Claws? For example, I can see how my Eldritch Blast can not be both a glaive and a claw- But I can see how the effect can be chained despite it being claws. 
The text of the feat says I can not use my normal Eldritch Blast. Does this mean no shapes or essences can be used in conjunction with it at all?

Comment: All of these questions are literally answered explicitly in the rules text that describes each of these things. This is not a good question. Please do a little more due diligence before asking others to spend their time doing it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Up to one of each. You cannot combine separate blast essences, or separate blast shapes.

> A warlock can apply one eldritch essence invocation to a single *eldritch blast*, choosing from any of the eldritch essence invocations he knows.

<sup>(*Complete Arcane* pg. 8)</sup>

> A warlock can apply only one blast shape at a time to an *eldritch blast*, and he can choose from any of the blast shape invocations that he knows.

<sup>(*Complete Arcane* pg. 9)</sup>

And the Eldritch Claws feat does not, as you might expect it to, give you a new blast shape invocation. It uses its own rules. Rules which say

> You cannot use your normal *eldritch blast* ability while your eldritch claws exist.

<sup>(*Dragon* vol. 358 pg. 87)</sup>

Since you aren’t using *eldritch blast* itself, and the rules for Eldritch Claws don’t say anything about blast shapes or eldritch essences, you do not have any ability to apply any of those things to Eldritch Claws. Eldritch Claws are a separate ability that just happens to scale along with your *eldritch blast*.

And it’s not like the authors didn’t know how to word their way around this: cf. Grappling Blast on the same page, which specifies that you “discharge your *eldritch blast* against the foe you’re grappling,” and “You may not add any blast shape invocations to your *eldritch blast* when using it in this manner,” which means you **can** use eldritch essences (since you are actually using *eldritch blast* and not just using a separate ability that scaled along with *eldritch blast*).

For the record, the best options for your blast shape and eldritch essence—by far—are *eldritch glaive* and *vitriolic blast*. If you aren’t doing the glaive-lock thing, none of the other shapes are really worth the invocation slot to learn. Maybe *eldritch chain*; you’re still making touch attacks and you don’t do any *worse* against the primary target. But it’s a very odd campaign where the immense length of *eldritch spear* comes into play, and all the others give up your ability to make a touch attack, instead forcing saving throws, or requiring a real attack. Either vastly diminishes the likelihood of the *eldritch blast* getting through. The non-*vitriolic* essences have similar problems, as they often change *eldritch blast* into some resistible damage type (instead of irresistible untyped damage), and then then tack on some rider effects with low reliability; with the warlock’s extremely limited invocations known, is very hard to justify. The only reason *vitriolic blast* is good is because acid resistance isn’t all *that* common, and turning *eldritch blast* into SR: No gives you an option for dealing with the one thing the regular *eldritch blast* has difficulty with.

Comment: And as I asked: How does this interact with Eldritch Claws? Since this is technically not a Blast Shape invocation, but a feat- Yet it does change the shape of the invocation.
I can't imagine my blast being both a glaive and claws, but I can imagine it being (for example) claws and chained.

Comment: Your second paragraph ignores *eldritch chain* - it's fairly ignorable, but still, it does use ranged touch attacks. Also, I edited in a citation - feel free to revert or alter, obviously.

Comment: @Arthaban I will address that as soon as I pull up the text—I was AFB when I started this and submitted just to not lose it—but in the meantime you could read that text yourself, because I know the Eldritch Claws feat text explicitly deals with that (can’t use either).

Comment: @Miniman Thanks, though you missed eldritch essences. It’s fine, I’m at my books now.

Comment: @miniman In my earlier comment, I used Eldritch Chain just as an example. In the original question I left it out because the question does not concern the chain, but the claws. I can edit the question to make that more apparent.

Comment: @Miniman Yup, forgot *eldritch chain* didn’t switch to Reflex saves. It’s decent enough; at least, unlike the others aside from *eldritch spear*, it isn’t a self-nerf.